# Cannot select multiple words to create an entity on

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am not able to select multiple words when creating an entity from an intent utterance. I've tried in both Chrome and Edge. This is all I can find on the web:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c1a985ff-83e3-4338-98cc-5bef318dad26/how-do-i-mark-multiple-words-to-be-a-single-entity?forum=LUIS

Comment: Answered my own question again. You do not "select" both words but instead click on the first word, then click on the second word.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is still an issue. I don't see the work around working for most of the browsers. However, I was able to resolve this issue by assigning different words to same entity and then using findAllEntities method and then merging the output. This is a bad workaround and I am expecting Microsoft to fix or guide us how to do it.

Comment: I've tried it in Edge and Chrome and it works. See my answer to my own question above. In order to select multiple words you click on each individually, it is not a hover or a drag, so if you have 3 words you click 3 times, once on each word.